# Error compiling R locally via bash file

Tags: r, linux, bash

I am trying to compile R locally using a bash file, but it fails and shows the following error:

```
tar: command not found
cd: R-3.2.5: No such file or directory
./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
R-3.2.5/lib64/R/bin/R: No such file or directory
sed: command not found
mv: command not found
tar: command not found
```

Bellow is the bash file I am submitting:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -xzvf R-3.2.5.tar.gz
cd R-3.2.5
./configure --prefix=$(pwd)
make
make install
cd ..
R-3.2.5/lib64/R/bin/R -e 'install.packages(c("BGLR"), 
repos="http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/", dependencies = TRUE)'
sed -i '/^R_HOME_DIR=/c R_HOME_DIR=$(pwd)/R' R-3.2.5/lib64/R/bin/R
mv R-3.2.5/lib64/R ./
tar -czvf R.tar.gz R/
```

When I run the same command lines directly on terminal it works fine, but when I try to run them using a bash file it fails.

Does anyone have an idea how to make it work?

Comment: In which shell are you running the commands? What's the output of `echo $0`? And `echo $PATH`? And `which bash`?

Answer (score 0):

The bash instance used to run the script doesn't seem to have the `$PATH` variable correctly set, so it can't find tar and the other commands.

Try replacing the 1st line with `#!/bin/bash -l`. Add `echo Path: $PATH` as the 2nd line and see if one of the directory listed actually contains tar. You should get something like `/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin/`.

Comment: I've done as you said, replacing the 1st line with #!/bin/bash -l; and adding echo Path: $PATH as the 2nd line.

I got this:

    Path: /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/dell/srvadmin/bin

I tested and the tar command can be called by     /usr/bin/tar

But, there are other commands that also fails.

I don't know if it make sense, but when I login in this machine and run both command lines or bash file, it works. However, I am trying to remotely submit a job from my computer to the server, when I do this it fails.

Comment: That's weird. Try replacing /bin/bash with /bin/sh